# facebook graph api event : invalid time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, time

I use below code to create a event, but I get `"error":{"message":"(#100) You must enter a valid date and time`

```
  $event_name = "New Event API Test Event";
  $event_start = time() + 60*60;  
  $event_privacy = "SECRET"; 


    $attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => $token,
                              'name' => $event_name,
                                    'start_time' => $event_start,
                                    'privacy_type' => $event_privacy
     );
```

`$event_start` returns `1349522919`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this `'start_time' => $event_start` line,

```
'start_time' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$event_start),
```

i think it helps you.

Comment: hi now i get message":"(#100) An event cannot have an end time in the past

Comment: I am not sure about the time format Facebook API accepts.Are you sure that you are passing the correct format.

Comment: Are you forgetting to account for timezones? there's some changes on the roadmap affecting how the API works with event times